# swift shorten code (functions class)

Tags: swift

i'm working on my first selfmade Application (called: "Busdriver")
and have a few questions.

To my person: I'm working with xCode and swift since nov 2016 and made my first Cardplay app. The App works fine, but i'm sure that there are many possibilitys to simplify my code.

So first of all: 
is there a way to remove a whole array within another array?
for example:

```
let cardValues = [["D2",2,"black],["D3",3,"black]["D4",4,"red]]
// i want to get this result:
// [["D2",2,"black],["D3",3,"black]]
```

and the other question is, is there a way to summerize the following lines of code:

```
var playingCards = [["♦2", 2, "red"], ["♦3", 3, "red"], ["♦4", 4, "red"], ["♦5", 5, "red"], ["♦6", 6, "red"], ["♦7", 7, "red"], ["♦8", 8, "red"], ["♦9", 9, "red"], ["♦10", 10, "red"], ["♦B", 11, "red"], ["♦D", 12, "red"], ["♦K", 13, "red"], ["♦A", 20, "red"], ["♥2", 2, "red"], ["♥3", 3, "red"], ["♥4", 4, "red"], ["♥5", 5, "red"], ["♥6", 6, "red"], ["♥7", 7, "red"], ["♥8", 8, "red"], ["♥9", 9, "red"], ["♥10", 10, "red"], ["♥B", 11, "red"], ["♥D", 12, "red"], ["♥K", 13, "red"], ["♥A", 20, "red"], ["♣2", 2, "black"], ["♣3", 3, "black"], ["♣4", 4, "black"], ["♣5", 5, "black"]]

var cardDeckPlayer1 = []
var cardDeckPlayer2 = []
var cardDeckPlayer3 = []
var cardDeckPlayer4 = []
var cardDeckPlayer5 = []
var cardDeckPlayer6 = []

let numberOfPlayers = 4 // this value varies from 2 to 6

if numberOfPlayers == 2
{
    cardDeckPlayer1.insert(playingCards[0], at: 0)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer1.insert(playingCards[0], at: 1)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer1.insert(playingCards[0], at: 2)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer1.insert(playingCards[0], at: 3)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)

    cardDeckPlayer2.insert(playingCards[0], at: 0)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer2.insert(SplayingCards[0], at: 1)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer2.insert(SpielKarten[0], at: 2)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer2.insert(playingCards[0], at: 3)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
}
if numberOfPlayers == 3
{
    cardDeckPlayer1.insert(playingCards[0], at: 0)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer1.insert(playingCards[0], at: 1)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer1.insert(playingCards[0], at: 2)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer1.insert(playingCards[0], at: 3)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)

    cardDeckPlayer2.insert(playingCards[0], at: 0)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer2.insert(playingCards[0], at: 1)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer2.insert(playingCards[0], at: 2)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer2.insert(playingCards[0], at: 3)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)

    cardDeckPlayer3.insert(playingCards[0], at: 0)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer3.insert(playingCards[0], at: 1)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer3.insert(playingCards[0], at: 2)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer3.insert(playingCards[0], at: 3)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
}
if numberOfPlayers == 4
{
    cardDeckPlayer1.insert(playingCards[0], at: 0)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer1.insert(playingCards[0], at: 1)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer1.insert(playingCards[0], at: 2)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer1.insert(playingCards[0], at: 3)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)

    cardDeckPlayer2.insert(playingCards[0], at: 0)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer2.insert(playingCards[0], at: 1)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer2.insert(playingCards[0], at: 2)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer2.insert(playingCards[0], at: 3)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)

    cardDeckPlayer3.insert(playingCards[0], at: 0)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer3.insert(playingCards[0], at: 1)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer3.insert(playingCards[0], at: 2)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer3.insert(playingCards[0], at: 3)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)

    cardDeckPlayer4.insert(playingCards[0], at: 0)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer4.insert(playingCards[0], at: 1)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer4.insert(playingCards[0], at: 2)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)
    cardDeckPlayer4.insert(playingCards[0], at: 3)
    playingCards.remove(at: 0)

    // etc. until if numberOfPlayers == 6...
```

So i want a function, class or whatever, that simplifys the code above, that depending on the numberOfPlayers value, 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 carddecks will be created and that this cardDecks exist of respectively the first 4 arrays within the playingCards Array.

so from Array `playingCards = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12], [13,14,15],[16,17,18],[19,20,21],[21,22,23], [24,25,26],[27,28,29],[30,31,32],[33,34,35],[36,37,38],[39,40,41],[42,43,44],[45,46,47]]`

the result should be like this:

```
numberOfPlayers = 3

cardDeckPlayer1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
cardDeckPlayer2 = [[13,14,15],[16,17,18],[19,20,21],[21,22,23]]
cardDeckPlayer3 = [[24,25,26],[27,28,29],[30,31,32],[33,34,35]]
// etc.
```

I#m not really into classes and structers and still have to learn a lot on this fields, but reading books has not helped me so far. So if someone could help me to make my Code more clearly structered, that would be great.

Thanks for helping, and sorry for bad english,
cyclopath

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to code review.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to develop a proper data model layer instead of storing things in arrays and subarrays. Here's one way to mode it:

```
struct Card: CustomStringConvertible {
    var rank: Rank
    var suit: Suit

    var color: Color {
        switch self.suit {
        case .spade, .club:    return .black
        case .heart, .diamond: return .red
        }
    }

    var description: String {
        return "\(suit.rawValue)\(rank.description) \(color.rawValue)"
    }

    enum Rank: Int, CustomStringConvertible {
        case two = 2, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten
        case jack, queen, king, ace

        var description: String {
            switch self {
            case .two, .three, .four, .five, .six, .seven, .eight, .nine, .ten:
                return "\(self.rawValue)"
            case .jack:
                return "J"
            case .queen:
                return "Q"
            case .king:
                return "K"
            case .ace:
                return "A"
            }
        }
    }

    enum Suit: String {
        case spade = "♠︎"
        case heart = "♥"
        case club = "♣"
        case diamond = "♦︎"
    }

    enum Color: String {
        case red = "red"
        case black = "black"
    }
}

struct Player {
    var deck = [Card]()

    static func byDistributing(cards: [Card], toNumberOfPlayers n: Int) -> [Player] {
        guard 2 <= n && n <= 6 else {
            fatalError("numberOfPlayer must be between 2 and 6")
        }
        guard cards.count % n == 0 else {
            fatalError("cards.count must be divisible by numberOfPlayers") // so every one got an equal-length deck
        }

        let numberOfCardsPerPlayer = cards.count / n
        let players = stride(from: 0, to: cards.count, by: numberOfCardsPerPlayer).map { i -> Player in
            let deck = Array(cards[i..<(i + numberOfCardsPerPlayer)])
            return Player(deck: deck)
        }

        return players
    }
}
```

It uses a lot of `enum` so you can't have card 1 or joker or anything like that. Now, I'm not a card player so you must pardon my ignorance about the makeup of a card deck. Here's how you construct a card deck:

```
// A standard 52-card deck in America
var playingCards = [Card]()
for suit in [Card.Suit.diamond, .heart, .club, .spade] {
    for value in 2...14 {
        let rank = Card.Rank(rawValue: value)!
        playingCards.append(Card(rank: rank, suit: suit))
    }
}

// Now distribute it among 4 players
let players = Player.byDistributing(cards: playingCards, toNumberOfPlayers: 4)
print(players[0].deck)   // all diamonds
print(players[1].deck)   // all hearts
print(players[2].deck)   // all clubs
print(players[3].deck)   // all spades
```

(Your next question is likely about how to shuffle a deck of cards so how we distribute these cards to the players in `byDistributing` doesn't really matter. They are supposed to be random anyway!)

Comment: `2 <= n && n <= 6` -> `2...6 ~= n`